# How to implement Refresh Tokens with some security?

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token, api-design

Each time a user logins, he get a new `access_token` and a new `refresh_token`.

When his `access_token` is expired, he uses his `refresh_token` to get a new `access_token`.

If an attacker somehow gets access to his `refresh_token`... then according to Oauth 2.0 [documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.4) :

> The authorization server could employ refresh token
> rotation in which a new refresh token is issued with every access
> token refresh response.  The previous refresh token is invalidated but
> retained by the authorization server.  If a refresh token is
> compromised and subsequently used by both the attacker and the
> legitimate client, one of them will present an invalidated refresh
> token, which will inform the authorization server of the breach.

So basically, if any `refresh_token` is used twice, I will notice the attack.

But what about if the legitimate user never uses his refresh token (which was stolen by an attacker) ? The attacker will be able to login and refresh over and over without the legitimate user being able to detect it.

Sounds like a rare situation ? What if you come to my place for a dinner and login with my computer and I get your refresh_token and access_token and you will never use this refresh_token again? Nobody will ever notice the attack.

What could solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

> Each time a user logins, he get a new access_token and a new
>   refresh_token

The client application gets these tokens, not the end-user.

> The attacker will be able to login and refresh over and over without
>   the legitimate user being able to detect it

To make any use of a refresh token you need the client's secret too.

> What if you come to my place for a dinner and login with my computer

I would never do that. I'm not that rude :)  What's for dinner?

Comment: Of course I meant client application ! Then, you say "client's secret" but when it's javascript app, how do I deal with such a thing ? I find no resources about it. As for the dinner, pastas.

Comment: a javascript app should use the implicit grant type which does not issue a refresh token, because a javascript app cannot keep a client secret. Pasta's good :)

Comment: Ok but then how every mobile app out there achieve authentification (without asking twice for credidentials). Authorization Server and Resouce server are the same server we built. Implicit flow means no refresh token, then how mobile apps out there achieve authentication ?

Comment: I think they make use of single-sign-on: Often a user remains logged in to their identity provider (e.g. facebook) then (for example) a mobile app which uses facebook, via oauth, will be able to get a new token regularly via the implicit grant without interaction with the user. The user will not be asked to log in as they are already logged in and have already consented to the scopes used by the mobile app.

Comment: try logging out of your IDPs (google, twitter, facebook ...) and then see what happens to any mobile app which uses them for OpenID or Oauth2.0.

Comment: Well then how do they do when they don't allow user to use third party oauth provider ? How does facebook itself ? I mean If I have my own server, my own native app, regular signup / login form, how do I do then ?

Comment: If your app deals with identity itself (no 3rd party oauth provider), then you can use cookies to prevent your users having to login everytime. When you first login, your app stores a browser cookie, indefinitely. The next time you visit the site, the cookie can be used to identify you. I hope I've answered the question for you - I don't want to go too far off topic!

Comment: I am sorry but I still don't have the answer to my question... Your answer helped a lot but I still don't get how to use refresh token to have virtually not expiring sessions, but with some security. Anybody who steals refresh token could be able to refresh it forever without anybody noticing... Maybe I should ask question different and more precise..